# How to ORDER BY a SUM() in JPQL

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, sql-order-by, jpql

Hi I want to use "order by" in JPQL.
the code I tried is

```
em.createQuery("SELECT o.productCode,SUM(o.quantity) FROM OrderDetailsEntity o GROUP BY o.productCode ORDER BY SUM(o.quantity)")
```

I have tried

```
em.createQuery("SELECT o.productCode,SUM(o.quantity) AS quant FROM OrderDetailsEntity o GROUP BY o.productCode ORDER BY quant")
```

Waiting for the answers :(

Comment: What is the problem? Any error?

Comment: for the FIRST code it was giving unexpected token SUM (it showed the SUM in ORDER BY).for the SECOND code it was giving unexpected token AS while expecting FROM.

Answer (score 1):

JPQL in JPA 1.0 was pretty restrictive.  What provider are you using?

Try EclipseLink 2.4.